# 'PFFacebookUitils.Type' does not have a member named 'initializeFacebook

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, swift

I am installing a facebook login to parse. the parse website at https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-facebook-users says:

There's also two code changes you'll need to make.        First, add the following to your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method, after you've initialized the Parse SDK.

```
// Import this header into your Swift bridge header   file
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>

// AppDelegate.swift
func application(application: UIApplication,      didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  Parse.setApplicationId("parseAppId",    clientKey:"parseClientKey")
  PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithLaunchOptions(launch    Options)
}
```

The parsestaterproject in the AppDelegate.swift says:

```
// If you are using Facebook, uncomment and add your   FacebookAppID to your bundle's plist as
    // described here:    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-   started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/
    // Uncomment the line inside ParseStartProject-   Bridging-Header and the following line here:


    //PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()
```

I have tried both *.initializeFacebook options and both give the same error:
    'PFFacebookUtils.Type' does not have a member named   'initializeFacebook ...

My code is:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//
//  Copyright 2011-present Parse Inc. All rights   reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Bolts
import Parse

// If you want to use any of the UI components, uncomment this line
// import ParseUI

// If you want to use Crash Reporting - uncomment this line
// import ParseCrashReporting

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    //--------------------------------------
    // MARK: - UIApplicationDelegate
    //--------------------------------------

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject:     AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

        //         **********************************************************    ******************
        // Uncomment this line if you want to enable Crash Reporting
        // ParseCrashReporting.enable()

            Parse.setApplicationId("RETRACTED_FOR_SECURITY", clientKey: "RETRACTED_FOR_SECURITY")

  // var pushSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert, categories: nil)

    // application.registerForRemoteNotifications(pushSettings)
    // application.registerForRemoteNotifications()



    //
    // If you are using Facebook, uncomment and add your FacebookAppID to your bundle's plist as
    // described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/
    // Uncomment the line inside ParseStartProject-Bridging-Header and the following line here:


    //PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebook()

        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    // ****************************************************************************

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var noPushPayload = false;
        if let options = launchOptions {
            noPushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil;
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: userNotificationTypes, categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }

    return true
}

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: Push Notifications
//--------------------------------------

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("", block: { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if succeeded {
            println("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.");
        } else {
            println("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.", error)
        }
    })
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        println("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        println("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Uncomment this method if you want to use Push Notifications with Background App Refresh
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
//     if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
//         PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
//     }
// }

//--------------------------------------
// MARK: Facebook SDK Integration
//--------------------------------------

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Uncomment this method if you are using Facebook
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
//     return FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, session:PFFacebookUtils.session())
// }

func application(application: UIApplication,
    openURL url: NSURL,
    sourceApplication: String?,
    annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,
            openURL: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}


}
```

my app-bridging-h file is:

```
    //  ParseStarterProject-Bridging-Header.h
    //
    //  Copyright 2011-present Parse Inc. All rights     reserved.
//

#define ParseStarterProject_Bridging_Header_h
#define ParseStarterProject_Bridging_Header_h

// If you are using Facebook, uncomment this line to     get automatic import of the header inside your project.
//#import <ParseFacebookUtils/PFFacebookUtils.h>


#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>


#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It should be: PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions). but note that while this solves this error, the code above still results in a different error which I will post in a different thread: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) –